# Font Issues: "Like Resource 58" error

Tags: front-end, warning-messages, character-encoding

I'm running Mathematica 9.0.0 on a Macbook Air with OSX 10.6.8 and I've recently started having issues with the font in the program. All special characters are being replaced with other characters in the INPUT and OUTPUT cells. So for example I would type "[ ]" and in Mathematica it would show as "@ D". Also a "LikeResource|c|58" error appears during each startup. Here are a few other examples of where the font is being switched:

Other examples:

"[ ]" ----> "@ D"

"{ }" ----> "8 ?"

"( )" ----> "H L"

"{9}" ----> ";9?"

This doesn't affect the processing of Mathematica at all but it makes it Very difficult to use and read other peoples notebooks. I've already tried clearing the BaseDirectory and reinstalling the program and even looking through FontBook to ensure none of the fonts are corrupted or duplicated. Can anyone help me out with this issue, thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Anything in the Console?

Comment: This has happened to me exactly once (on 10.6.x too, if I remember right) and restarting _Mathematica_ fixed it for me. I could never get it to happen again (and didn't take screenshots), so didn't think it was worth emailing support. It has never happened in 10.7.x and 10.8.x, so you might consider updating...

Comment: Did you see [this](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3382)?

Comment: I have looked at that exact link, unfortunately with no luck. I followed all the steps and no fix..

Comment: @Cyrus, I had a 'similar'issue [Link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17639/wolfram-alpha-double-sign-not-shown-anymore) and basically had installed the latest version etc. At the end I removed all mathematica files that I could find and reinstalled again with succes.

Comment: There are a couple of things that would help us understand the issue better.
1. Open Finder and navigate to the Applications folder. Right-click or Ctrl-Click Mathematica in Applications and select Show Package Contents. A new window will open. Navigate to SystemFiles > Fonts> TrueType. There should be only one file in this folder called MathematicaFonts.dfont. Is there anything else in this folder. Additionally, Are the file permissions on this folder set so that it can be read by everyone?

Comment: 2. Open up FontBook again. Do you see any Mathematica fonts? These begin with the word "Math". Try uninstalling these fonts if you find them.

Comment: 3. Running Mathematica from the terminal should give a more information error message. Specifically, it would help to see an error code. Please open Finder and navigate to the Applications folder. Right-click or Ctrl-Click Mathematica in Applications and select Show Package Contents. A new window will open. Navigate to Contents > MacOS and then click on Mathematica to run it. You will also see a terminal open. What do you end up seeing in the terminal when you get the LikeResource error message?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same error today, and solved it by following the instructions in the [link](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3382) that @VLC posted. I validated my Fonts, reinstalled Mathematica, and started the app with clean prefs. None of those steps solved the problem on their own, but after a restart everything was back to normal. So, possibly not all of the steps were required.